# Adding Help Tooltips To SharePoint ASPX Form Fields

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, custom-form, aspx, jquery-ui, help

I have an existing custom ASPX form that captures data to a SharePoint list.  A new requirement has been received to provide fly-out tooltip type in-line help boxes on fields to make it easier for users to understand what they are filling in.

I was hoping to pull the text for the tooltips from a separate SharePoint list for each field into the form.

Are there any pre-made libraries that provide something like this or should I go down the route of creating something from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this threads.

http://spjsblog.com/2012/02/24/form-field-tooltip-for-sharepoint-2007-and-sharepoint-2010/

---

You'll have to modify add/new/edit forms of the list or document library you are working with.
Then you can use any of the numerous tooltip js libraries i.e. http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ to add tooltips to your form.